# HTML dataset is empty

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

I am using HTML, JS and pass via Thymleaf a value to a `td` element as you can see below.

```
  <tr th:each="car : ${cars}">
        <td id="reduceCheckbox" data-th-value="${car.isReduced()}"></td>
    </tr>
```

This is available in the HTML element

[image]

But when I try to retrieve the value from the dataset there is nothing present in the set (lenght = 0)

I also found some suggestions to use `getAttribute` instead but this is not delivering the value as well.

```
  let cbs = document.getElementsByTagName('td')
  for (let i = 0; i < cbs.length; i++) {
    if (cbs[i].id === 'reduceCheckbox' || cbs[i].id === 'slCheckbox') {
      console.log(cbs[i].dataset) /*length = 0*/
      console.log(cbs[i].dataset.value) /*undefined*/
      console.log(cbs[i].dataset.thvalue)  /*undefined*/
     /* console.log(cbs[i].dataset.th-value) */ /*value is not defined*/
      console.log(cbs[i].getAttribute("data-th-value")) /*null*/
      console.log(cbs[i].getAttribute("data-value")) /*null*/
      if (cbs[i].dataset.thvalue === 'true') {
        cbs[i].innerHTML = activeCheckbox
      }
      else {
        cbs[i].innerHTML = inactiveCheckbox
      }
    }
  }
```

Any idea how can I proceed that my if/else block is getting the relevant data?

I was already considering to form this td element to a string and just check if it contains `value=true` or `value=false` but it seems a bit to dirty for me.

Comment: The screen capture of your td shows that it does not have any data elements on it at all.

Comment: ^^ ...and so it would appear that Thymeleaf is processing the attribute itself and then removing it.

Comment: Ok I am pretty new to HTML but your hint that there is no data-element gave me a solution how to access it. Ty =)